# While running a Python script, I'm getting an error

Tags: python, python-2.x, telnet

While running the Python script below, I'm am getting an error:

```
 [root@localhost ~]# cat pythonR5script1
 import getpass
 import sys
 import telnetlib

 HOST = "100.100.100.1"
 user = raw_input("Enter your telnet username: ")
 password = getpass.getpass()

 tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

 tn.read_until("username: ")
 tn.write(user + "\r\n")
 if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\r\n")

tn.write("enable\r\n")
tn.write("cisco\r\n")
tn.write("conf t\r\n")
tn.write("int loop 0\r\n")
tn.write("ip add 200.200.200.1 255.255.255.255\r\n")
tn.write("end\r\n")
tn.write("exit\r\n")


print tn.read_all()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
[root@localhost ~]# python pythonR5script1 
Enter your telnet username: alan
Password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonR5script1", line 14, in <module>
tn.read_until("Password: ")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 294, in read_until
return self._read_until_with_poll(match, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 343, in _read_until_with_poll
return self.read_very_lazy()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 455, in read_very_lazy
raise EOFError, 'telnet connection closed'
EOFError: telnet connection closed
```

Please kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: You almost certainly should not be running this as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing strings while the write function expects **byte strings.**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html?highlight=telnetlib#telnetlib.Telnet.write

> Telnet.write(buffer)
>        Write a **byte string** to the socket, doubling any IAC characters. This can block if the connection is blocked. May raise OSError if the
>   connection is closed.

Execute encode() function on the strings you send to server.

`tn.write('{}\r\n'.format(user).encode())`